# Laravel/Eloquent collitions with model traits

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.8 for my project, and i am getting the error `Bad call Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::withSum()`  because I removed `LaravelSubQueryTrait` in my traits. When i re-add `LaravelSubQueryTrait`, my project does not run, I am getting this error  `Trait method newBaseQueryBuilder has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\Traits\TestModelTrait`. Upgrading to laravel 8.x is not an option at this point and I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong. Any tips/advise/ resources to read will be highly appreciated to help solve my problem. Thanks

My TestmodelTrait is as below :

```
use Alexmg86\LaravelSubQuery\Traits\LaravelSubQueryTrait;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Watson\Rememberable\Rememberable;

trait MedyqModelTrait
{
    protected static $skipUuid = false;

    use MedyqTrait, SoftDeletes, Rememberable, LaravelSubQueryTrait;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function ($record) {

            if (!self::$skipUuid) {
                $record->{'uuid'} = (string)Str::orderedUuid();
            }

            if (auth()->check()) {
                $record->{'created_by'} = auth()->id();
                $record->{'updated_by'} = auth()->id();
            }
        });

        self::updating(function ($record) {

            if (auth()->check()) {
                $record->{'updated_by'} = auth()->id();
            }

        });

        self::updated(function ($record) {

            $record->flushCache();

        });

        self::deleted(function ($record) {

            if (auth()->check()) {

                $record->{'deleted_by'} = auth()->id();

                $record->save();
            }

        });

        self::restored(function ($record) {

            if (auth()->check()) {

                $record->{'restored_by'} = auth()->id();

                $record->{'restored_at'} = Carbon::now();

                $record->save();
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }

    public function scopeAlive($query)
    {
        $query->where("status", config("constants.status.alive"));
    }

}
```

My TestTrait looks like this :

```
use App\Entities\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait MedyqTrait
{
    public static function getTableName()
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        $query->where("status", config("constants.status.active"));
    }

    public function scopeInActive($query)
    {
        $query->where("status", config("constants.status.inactive"));
    }

    /**
     * Mass (bulk) insert for Postgres Laravel 5
     *
     * insert([
     *   ['id'=>1,'value'=>10],
     *   ['id'=>2,'value'=>60]
     * ]);
     *
     *
     * @param array $rows
     * @param null $table
     * @param bool $skipUUid
     * @param bool $timestamps
     * @param bool $authorstamp
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function bulkInsert(array $rows, $table = null, $skipUUid = false, $timestamps = true, $authorstamp = true)
    {
        $return_values = array_filter($rows, 'is_array');
        if (!count($return_values) > 0) {
            throw new Exception("This function expects a multidimensional associative array");
        }

        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = DB::getTablePrefix() . $this->getTable();
        }

        $rows = array_map(function ($item) use ($skipUUid, $timestamps, $authorstamp) {
            $authenticated = auth()->check();
            $authorId = auth()->id();
            $time = Carbon::now();
            if (!$skipUUid) {
                $item['uuid'] = Str::orderedUuid();
            }
            if ($timestamps && !key_exists('created_by', $item) && $authenticated && $authorstamp) {
                $item['created_by'] = $authorId;
            }
            if ($timestamps && !key_exists('updated_by', $item) && $authenticated && $authorstamp) {
                $item['updated_by'] = $authorId;
            }
            if ($timestamps && !key_exists('created_at', $item)) {
                $item['created_at'] = $time;
            }
            if ($timestamps && !key_exists('updated_at', $item)) {
                $item['updated_at'] = $time;
            }
            return $item;
        }, $rows);

        $first = reset($rows);

        $columns = implode(',',
            array_map(function ($value) {
                return "$value";
            }, array_keys($first))
        );

        $values = implode(',', array_map(function ($row) {
                return '(' . implode(',',
                        array_map(function ($value) {
                            return "'" . str_replace("'", "''", $value) . "'";
                        }, $row)
                    ) . ')';
            }, $rows)
        );


        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table}({$columns}) VALUES {$values}";

        return DB::statement($sql);
    }

    public function deletedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "deleted_by", "id");
    }
}
```

Comment: `withSum()` is not stardard Eloquent so I'm guessing that you have a macro there, right? Can you show the code for that as well?

Comment: @Cosmin, i am using this ``` use Alexmg86\LaravelSubQuery\Traits\LaravelSubQueryTrait ``` in my traits

Comment: I think the error has no related with Laravel version, and upgrade to 8 will not help. Review your method names, to identify the duplicate (remove one by one until the error dissappears)

Answer (score 1):

Guess you have problem with the syntax.

```php
$invoice = Invoice::where('id', $invoice->id)
    ->with('items')
    ->withSum('items', 'total_amount')
    ->withSum('items', 'amount_paid')
    ->first();
```

`withSum` is probably available only since Laravel version 8.x, before that I think only `withCount` was available. But if you still want to use withSum in earlier version you can define a macro'

Answer (score 1):

You could also try use LaravelSubQueryTrait trait directly in the model/models.

```
use Alexmg86\LaravelSubQuery\Traits\LaravelSubQueryTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use LaravelSubQueryTrait;
```

Reference https://github.com/Alexmg86/laravel-sub-query